# Problem with umnet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dependencies

I did a fresh installation of ubuntu 14.04, did updates and upgrades, when i tried installing softwares smplayer, synaptic package manager, ubuntu-restricted-extras, gdebi, etc.. getting a umnet dependencies error.

Here is the `sudo apt-get update` error message

```
Fetched 675 kB in 1min 20s(8,339B/s)                                         
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is the /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
    # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

**T**ried changing the server to `main server` but still fails to fetch `restricted/source/Sources`.

Dependency Errors for various installs

For smplayer

```
#sudo apt-get install smplayer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 smplayer : Depends: mplayer but it is not installable or
                     mplayer-nogui but it is not installable or
                     mpv (>= 0.6.2) but it is not installable
            Recommends: smplayer-themes but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: smplayer-skins but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: smtube but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

For ubuntu-restricted-extras:

```
#sudo apt-get ubuntu-restricted-extras

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-restricted-extras : Depends: ubuntu-restricted-addons but it is not installable
                            Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not installable
                            Recommends: unrar but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse but it is not installable
                            Recommends: libavcodec-extra but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

For gdebi :

```
#sudo apt-get install gdebi

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdebi : Depends: gksu but it is not installable
         Recommends: libgtk2-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried using `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix for broken packages but there are no broken packages.

Also tried adding `MultiArchitecture` to thinking it might solve `umnet dependency` problem but no luck at all.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Tried to build the dependencies with package using

```
#apt-get build-dep smplayer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Build-Depends dependency for smplayer cannot be satisfied because the package debhelper cannot be found
```

Tried installing `debhelper` but no luck

```
#sudo apt-get install debhelper

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package debhelper is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  dh-apparmor

E: Package 'debhelper' has no installation candidate
```

Can't find a way to resolve these dependencies problem. Please post a way to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change Indian mirror to main server.

Comment: @Pilot6 tried that still not working mentioned that in my question

Comment: Run the command `sudo apt-get update` and paste the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give us the link.